# Alternatives of switch

Tags: c++, switch-statement

In the below code, I need help with the alternatives of switch case, I mean how can I avoid switch and use the other option to execute the code.

Code:

```
cout << " *********************Intensive Program 1***********************\n\n" << endl;
cout << "\nHere's the menu of choices: ";
cout << "\n1. Add a Circle.\n";
cout << "2. Print a Circle. \n";
cout << "3. Print all Cricles \n";
cout << "4. Exit.\n";
cout << "\nPlease enter your choice: ";
cin >> choice;
while (choice <4){
    switch (choice){

        case 1:
            // For adding cirles to the class 
            cout << " Enter the value for the radius of the circle: ";
            cin >> radius;
            cout << " Enter the value for the center of the circle: ";
            cin >> center;
            myCircle[thisPosition] = new Circle(radius, center);
            myCircle[thisPosition]->PrintCircle();
            thisPosition++;
            break;

        case 2:  // For printing a particular cirle from the list of cirles
            cout << " Enter the Value for which Circle to Print: ";
            cin >> printPosition;
            myCircle[printPosition - 1]->PrintCircle();
            break;

        case 3:  // For printing all the circles in the class object array pointer list
            cout << "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < thisPosition; i++){
                myCircle[i]->PrintCircle();
                cout << "\n==============================" << endl;
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "\n Good Bye !!! \n " << endl;
            break;
        }       
        cout << "\nHere's the menu of choices: ";
        cout << "\n1. Add a Circle.\n";
        cout << "2. Print a Circle. \n";
        cout << "3. Print all Cricles \n";
        cout << "4. Exit.";
        cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your other option is to use a bunch of 'if/else if' style statements, but in this scenario, switch is a better choice.

Comment: What "other option/alternative" are you referring to? A `switch` statement is probably the best thing to use in this case.

Comment: There are a number of options, including a bunch of `if` and `goto` statements. Tell us *why* you want to avoid `switch` would be tremendously helpful in giving you an answer that's actually useful. What is the **actual problem** you're trying to solve? I suspect you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167210).

Comment: Whatever gives the easiest to read and modify program. Given today's compilers, I'd be surprised if (while at least mildly optimizing) the object code is any different.

Comment: Tables of function pointers are good choices when dealing with multiple menus.

Comment: If I use switch, I m having a need to write "cout << "\nHere's the menu of choices: ";
        cout << "\n1. Add a Circle.\n";
        cout << "2. Print a Circle. \n";
        cout << "3. Print all Cricles \n";
        cout << "4. Exit.";
        cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice; twice, how do I solve it so that I have to use it only once

Comment: I updated my answer based on this comment

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a `std::vector<std::function<void()>> choices(5);`... and call it like `choices[choice]();` after you filled it with the alternative choices like `choices[1] = &function_1;` etc...

But I have a feeling the real question is not *really* about how to avoid `switch`...

[EDIT]

Based on your comment, I think the question is how to avoid duplicating the "menu" output. Simply refactor like this using a `do..while`:

```cpp
cout << " *********************Intensive Program 1***********************\n\n" << endl;
cout << "\nHere's the menu of choices: ";
cout << "\n1. Add a Circle.\n";
cout << "2. Print a Circle. \n";
cout << "3. Print all Cricles \n";
cout << "4. Exit.\n";
cout << "\nPlease enter your choice: ";
do
{
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice){

        case 1:
            // For adding cirles to the class 
            cout << " Enter the value for the radius of the circle: ";
            cin >> radius;
            cout << " Enter the value for the center of the circle: ";
            cin >> center;
            myCircle[thisPosition] = new Circle(radius, center);
            myCircle[thisPosition]->PrintCircle();
            thisPosition++;
            break;

        case 2:  // For printing a particular cirle from the list of cirles
            cout << " Enter the Value for which Circle to Print: ";
            cin >> printPosition;
            myCircle[printPosition - 1]->PrintCircle();
            break;

        case 3:  // For printing all the circles in the class object array pointer list
            cout << "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < thisPosition; i++){
                myCircle[i]->PrintCircle();
                cout << "\n==============================" << endl;
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "\n Good Bye !!! \n " << endl;
            break;
        }       
        system("pause");
    }
} while(choice != 4);
```

If you still want the menu to be repeated for each choice, then simply cut and paste the menu printing at the start of the `do..while` loop.

As a side note, I strongly suggest you read https://mikeash.com/getting_answers.html for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Using if-else ladder is one of the alternatives for switch statements.

```
cout << " *********************Intensive Program 1***********************\n\n" << endl;
cout << "\nHere's the menu of choices: ";
cout << "\n1. Add a Circle.\n";
cout << "2. Print a Circle. \n";
cout << "3. Print all Cricles \n";
cout << "4. Exit.\n";
cout << "\nPlease enter your choice: ";
cin >> choice;
while (choice <4){

    if(choice==1)
    {
        // For adding cirles to the class 
        cout << " Enter the value for the radius of the circle: ";
        cin >> radius;
        cout << " Enter the value for the center of the circle: ";
        cin >> center;
        myCircle[thisPosition] = new Circle(radius, center);
        myCircle[thisPosition]->PrintCircle();
        thisPosition++;
     }   
    else if(choice==2)
    {  // For printing a particular cirle from the list of cirles
        cout << " Enter the Value for which Circle to Print: ";
        cin >> printPosition;
        myCircle[printPosition - 1]->PrintCircle();
    }
    else if(choice==3)  // For printing all the circles in the class object array pointer list
    {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < thisPosition; i++){
            myCircle[i]->PrintCircle();
            cout << "\n==============================" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n Good Bye !!! \n " << endl;
    }
    }       
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: A table of function pointers or similar is a better replacement for switch statements with sequential values.